# How to show Sqlite Triggers Raise message in toast

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I'm trying to use sqlite trigger before inserting concept for validation in android studio. I'm using 3 fields - farmer_id, farmer_name, father_name and if farmer_name is empty am trying to show an error message as "Farmer Name is mandatory". So I used trigger coding as below in android studio

```
String farmer_insert_trigger = "CREATE TRIGGER insert_validation" +
            "BEFORE INSERT on farmer_det" +
            "BEGIN SELECT CASE WHEN new.farmer_name IS '' THEN" +
            "RAISE(ABORT,'Farmer Name is mandatory')" +
            "end;" +
            "end;";
public void createTriggers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(farmer_insert_trigger);
    }
```

when I hit "Submit" button to show the error message as "Farmer Name is mandatory" am getting the error message as *"near "SELECT":syntax error (code 1);, while compliling CREATE Triger...".* Below is my button click event.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(v->{
            String farmerID = farmer_id.getText().toString();
            String farmerName = farmer_name.getText().toString();
            String fatherName = father_name.getText().toString();

            try {
                // Execute insert function
                dbHandler.createTriggers();
            } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Just in case the above doesn't catch it
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }        
        });
```

Did I missed any syntax while creating trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are missing spaces where they are required/needed.

Try :-

```
String farmer_insert_trigger = "CREATE TRIGGER insert_validation /*SPACE*/" +
            "BEFORE INSERT on farmer_det /*SPACE*/" +
            "BEGIN SELECT CASE WHEN new.farmer_name IS '' THEN /*SPACE*/" +
            "RAISE(ABORT,'Farmer Name is mandatory')" +
            "end;" +
            "end;";
```

- Obviously comments `/*SPACE*/` not needed.

Comment: Yes it is working fine...is there any way to get the raise message alone - Farmer Name is mandatory. Since am calling the full triggers am getting the full triggers code in my toast.

Comment: @Venkatesh just have the message as a constant and use it in the abort and the toast.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT, you mean to say like, ` String err_ins = "Farmer Name is mandatory";` and passing this to ` "RAISE(ABORT,err_ins)" +`... something like this I need to use...plz correct me if am wrong...

Comment: @Venkatesh More like `public static final String ERR_INS = "Farmer Name is mandatory";` code it in a suitable class and you can access it anywhere. Similar to how you can use `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` i.e. the `Toast` class will have something like `public static final int LENGTH_SHORT = 1; `

Answer (score 0):

To show SQLite toast message in toast, we can use REGEX expression. I have used below set of code to display the needed message within single quotes (which is in RAISE).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*'([^']*)'.*");
                Matcher m1 = p.matcher(str);
                if (m1.matches()) {
                    // Print the required sub-string
                    System.out.println("Extracted part : "+ m1.group(1));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+m1.group(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if a String is empty from program directly like this :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(v->{
        String farmerID = farmer_id.getText().toString();
        String farmerName = farmer_name.getText().toString();
        String fatherName = father_name.getText().toString();

        if (farmerName.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Farmer Name is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Execute insert function
            }        
    });
```

The program can compile faster because you don't need to check the database and the code is simpler.

Comment: Yes @Rahmad....But I need to show the error message from SQLite triggers, which I have created in Trigger as "Farmer Name is mandatory"...

Comment: @Venkatesh It seems like your create trigger syntax missing some spaces